# Install 3dmax on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, 3ds-max

I have to install 3d max on ubuntu 12.04 cloud, I want to use this for rendering purpose. Need suggestion is it possible to install complete 3d max on linux with VRay plugin.

Comment: There is no Linux version of 3ds max, and I don't believe there us a Linux version of Vray either. You could try running it through wine, although I'm not sure if that would work very well. Does it have to be Max and Vray? There are other programs that do work on Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [WineHQ - 3D Studio Max 9.x](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=8544) the latest version 3D Studio MAX works "perfectly" in Windows 7 mode in Ubuntu-based distributions running in Wine 1.7. To install Wine 1.7 in Ubuntu 12.04, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install wine1.7 winetricks
```

Blender (*blender*) is a very fast and versatile 3D modeller/renderer application that is available in the default Ubuntu repositories. Blender is a nice application, especially the more recent versions of Blender, but it is complicated and has a steep learning curve.